# How to copy relative location and rotation changes from bone to bone using bone constraints?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, bone.constraints

I've spend too many hours wrapping my head around this problem, so looks like its time to reach the internet for help.

###### The need

I have [mixamo](https://mixamo.com) animation to which I'm trying to set up root motion bone (`RootBone` in attached `.blend` file). I'd like to keep `RootBone` at initial `(0, 0, 0)` location, and facing Blender's `-Y` axis (bone rest state in attached `.blend` file) and I have two topics:

1. How to apply `mixamorig:Hips` bone `X`, `Y` and `Z` location relative difference to have `RootBone` jiggle a little bit up and down (due to hips movement) while being constantly under hips bone around the ground level?
2. How to apply `mixamorig:Hips` bone `Z` rotation difference to have `RootBone` rotated from its initial position?

Is this even possible with bone constraints?

[image]

###### Tries and errors

Below, we have screenshots of root motion bone in rest position:

[image: root motion bone rest position]

I would like to have this particular alignment and on top of that, add hips bone changes.

Following simple setup of bone constraints:

[image: root motion bone constraints]

Produces following results:

[image: root motion bone with basic constraints]

At first animation frame, `RootBone` is already rotated, but it should stay the same (marked in yellow line), as in rest position. Also height of `RootBone` is not at the ground (yellow line) but at the level of hips.

Regardless of the setup, I can't make `Copy Location` constraint to keep offset but still have hips vertical changes. Also, even enabling `Offset` in `Copy Location` is not working with `Z` axis, (in oppose that `Offset` effect in other axes produces expected results) - I would like to keep the offset, but still apply `Z` axis changes.

###### Side notes

I'm using Blender in version `3.5.0`.